# freeglut - a smooth camera rotation using mouse

Tags: math, opengl, 3d, freeglut

When I rotate my fps camera using mouse the animation is not smooth. When I use a keyboard everything works nice. For keyboard I use an array of type bool to buffer keys. What Can I do to make the animation smooth when using mouse ?

```
void MousePassiveMotion(int x, int y)
{
     int centerX = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2;
     int centerY = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2;

     int deltaX =  x - centerX;
     int deltaY =  y - centerY;

     if(deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0) 
     {
          heading = deltaX * 0.2f;
          pitch = deltaY  * 0.2f;
          glutWarpPointer(centerX, centerY);
     }
}
```

Comment: What is "not smooth" about it? Can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: It looks like there is not enough FPS, but in fact the frame rate equals 60. A similar effect you can get without using an array of type bool to buffer keys when you perform some actions directly in glutKeyboardFunc

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when the mouse polling rate and the screen refresh rate are not of a good ratio, updating the display based on the mouse position can result in a jerky effect.

You have vertical sync on, correct?  And if you turn it of the mouse movement is smoother at the expense of tearing?

One option is to use a smoothing function, that "lags" the values you use for the mouse position just a tiny bit behind the real mouse position

The gist of it goes like this:

```
float use_x,use_y;      // position to use for displaying
float springiness = 50; // tweak to taste.

void smooth_mouse(float time_d,float realx,float realy) {
    double d = 1-exp(log(0.5)*springiness*time_d);

    use_x += (realx-use_x)*d;
    use_y += (realy-use_y)*d;
}
```

This is an [exponential decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) function.  You call it every frame to establish what to use for a mouse position. The trick is getting the right value for `springiness`.  To be pedantic, `springiness` is the number of times the distance between the real mouse position and the used position will halve.  For smoothing mouse movement, a good value for `springiness` is probably 50-100.

`time_d` is the interval since the last mouse poll.  Pass it the real time delta (in fractional seconds) if you can, but you can get away with just passing it `1.0/fps`.

If you have a WebGL-capable browser you can see a live version [here](http://knobbits.org/webgl/widgets.html) - look for a class called `GLDraggable` in `viewer.js`.

Comment: Yes. Turning off vsync doesn't have an influence on the smoothness. In my code adding "lags" looks like this: int deltaX = (x - centerX) *d, int deltaY = (y - centerY) * d and then the movement is a little bit smoother

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this instead where the camera angles are calculated with the last position of your mouse instead of the center point of your screen.

```
void mouseMove( int x, int y )
{
   theta += (lastx-x) / 100.0;
   phi += (lasty-y) / 50.0;
   lastx = x;
   lasty = y;

   if ( phi >= M_PI )
      phi = M_PI - 0.001;
   else if ( phi <= 0 )
      phi = 0.001;
}
```

Here 100.0 and 50.0 are factors that influence the speed of the movement (sensitivity) and the if / else statement limits the movement to certain angles.

Comment: I need to retain a cursor in the middle of the screen because I implemented a fps camera. Moreover I don't understand what are advantages of your solution.