# Move camera without lag in libgdx

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, lag

I just started a small project with libgdx and I noticed that the camera is lagging behind the mouse a bit. I am moving it like that: (I have cut out everything else)

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenXlast = screenX;
    screenYlast = screenY;

    if (button == Input.Buttons.RIGHT || pointer > 0) {
        rightMouseKlicked = true;

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (button == Input.Buttons.RIGHT) {
        rightMouseKlicked = false;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    if (rightMouseKlicked) {

        gamecam.translate((screenXlast - screenX) * gamecam.zoom, (screenY -
            screenYlast) * gamecam.zoom);

    }
    screenXlast = screenX;
    screenYlast = screenY;
    return false;
}
```

The game runs at 60fps but it seems like the output is delayed by a few frames. (the mouse cursor does not stay at the same position on the map while moving it around)

Is there an other way of doing it, so that the camera stays up with the mouse?

Comment: gamecam.translate((screenXlast - screenX) * gamecam.zoom, (screenY -
            screenYlast) * gamecam.zoom) is missing the delta value to correct your transformations according to actual fps. Allthough there might be another cause of your problem you should always apply delta to your transformations.

Comment: Please show your `resize` method.

Comment: what do you mean by resize method?

Comment: The one in your game or screen class. Was trying to find out your relationship between screen dimension and camera dimensions.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my problem. The map is moving to the right position, but it does it about 50ms behind the mouse. Here is a Screenshot: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4295/i8utxi4u_png.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, events in libgdx go into a stack. It is possible to receive the event a few ms after it actually happened.

You can see that if you draw an actor or a texture of the position of the touch dragged event - if you drag fast you will see that the drawn texture is always behind your mouse (or finder on phones).

As @Jankapunkt said, you can try multiplying the position by the delta time (*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*) but I am not sure that it will help

Comment: Why do I need delta, when it is not depending on it? On every frame, regardless of how long it takes to render I want the cam to be moved as much as the mouse moved. My code works just fine and you can drag around the map perfectly, but the only problem is, that it is so laggy. I'm shure that that has nothing to  do with  the "missing" delta.   EDIT: Ups it was an answer to the other comment. Klicked the wrong button

Comment: When i am multiplying the amout of pixels it moved since the last frame (i guess thats what you mean by multiplying the position) It may catch up better with the mouse but when you stop the mouse it will overshoot. I don't want that.In other games / programms you can move stuff around with the mouse without lag. Isnt't that possible at all with libgdx?

Comment: Isn't it possible to get the newest inputs in the queue and ignore the rest? It has to be possible. In windows, when you move windows around they stick to the mouse perfectly.

Comment: Is it for windows, or for smartphones?

Comment: It can run on both. But for my problem it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the screen pixels moved, but not scaling to the size of your camera's viewport. Modify it as shown:

```
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    if (rightMouseKlicked) {
        float scale = gamecam.zoom * gamecam.viewportWidth / (float)(Gdx.graphics.getWidth);
        gamecam.translate((screenXlast - screenX) * scale , (screenY -
            screenYlast) * scale );

    }
    screenXlast = screenX;
    screenYlast = screenY;
    return false;
}
```

Also keep in mind that a typical mouse's update rate is pretty low (about 10 FPS I think). If you find camera movement too jerky, you'll have to calculate mouse movement speed and extrapolate the mouse's position and add a smoothing algorithm on top of that. [See here for discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212586/freeglut-a-smooth-camera-rotation-using-mouse) (3D but still generally applies).

Comment: Your code gives the exact same results as mine. I scaled it by using gamecam.zoom.

Comment: I filmed it now with my phone. When pausing the video you can see  the 5 last cursors and you can clearly see, that the map is lagging behind by 3 frames which is 50ms.

Comment: Oh and the mouse ist updated with the same framerate the graphics are updated. I put this code inside touchDragged():     System.out.println(1.0/((double)(System.nanoTime() - lastTime) / 1000000000.0));
        lastTime = System.nanoTime();     and it prints the same numbers as fraps shows.

Comment: If the results are the same, then your camera must be sized the same as your screen. I think I misinterpreted what you mean by lag. Do you have a high-end mouse? Mine updates at around 10 FPS.

Comment: I have a Razer Naga. I posted a screenshot above, so you can see what I mean.